# Bitcoin node setup through Proton vpn possible?

Tags: full-node

Anyone able to get a bitcoin node to communicate through proton vpn?
Protonvpn does offer port forwarding. but i had no luck. bitnodes.io isnt finding it.
https://protonvpn.com/support/port-forwarding/

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but I didn't use port-forwarding. I used split-tunneling.

This excludes Bitcoin Core from going through the vpn and opens up port 8333 to the internet.

If you'd like the details for this, let me know, I'll be happy to post them.

Comment: Hello, it would be appropriate for you to post the solution if you have found it. Basic details / steps are fine. This will ensure that any future visitors with the same question may be able to use your answer as a guide.